# Can I put a file that doesn't exist (yet) in an HLS playlist?

Tags: http-live-streaming

In MPEG-DASH, I can create a static* MPD for live content by listing all of the media segments that I intend to provide at the very beginning, and then setting the `MPD@availabilityTime` appropriately. A client can figure out segment availability times as `MPD@availabilityTime` + `SegmentBase@availabilityTimeOffset` + segment time.

* Static as in not-changing, not `MPD@type="static"`

What I'm wondering is, is something similar allowed for HLS? Specifically, could I create an HLS playlist with a bunch of files that don't exist yet, and then create the files over time? If I did, is there any way to indicate to a client when it should expect those files to appear (the segment availability time in DASH)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The HLS playlist should list the available segments. The closest thing you can get is using an [Event playlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-EVENT_PLAYLIST) but it's not static as you need to refresh it when a new segment becomes available until you reach the last one and add the `EXT-X-ENDLIST`.

You can find the HLS specification here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13